# Can I use the binomial distribution probability mass function if the data is not normal?

Tags: probability

For example, I want to know the probability that a venture fund that invests in 10 startups will end up with at least 2 startups that are worth more than 5 billion.

Let's assume that the probability of investing in a startup that ends up being worth 1 billion or more is 1% and that the distribution of startup valuations 1 billion or more is as follows:

| Bin (billions) | Cumulative Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 1-5 | 87% |
| 5-10 | 95% |
| >10 | 100% |

The distribution of startup valuations 1 billion or more is not normally distributed.

Can I compute the probability of having at least 2 startups that are worth more than 5 billion out of a portfolio of 10 startups like this?

P(x>=2) = 1 - [ P(x=0) + P(x=1) ]

Where the probability of investing in a startup worth at least 5 billion is equal to 1% x (1-87%) = 0.0013

and where

P(x=0) = $\binom{10}0 $ $(0.0013^0)$ $(1-0.0013)^{(10-0)} $

P(x=1) = $\binom{10}1 $ $(0.0013^1)$ $(1-0.0013)^{(10-1)} $

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is reasonable under the assumption that each startup's valuation is independent and identically distributed.  Normality of the valuation is not required because the probability of interest is being calculated for a *dichotomous* or *binary* outcome, namely, whether the valuation exceeds a certain threshold.  As such, under the aforementioned independence assumption, the question of whether a given startup meets this criterion or not amounts to the observation of a single Bernoulli trial whose probability of success $p$ equals the probability of meeting the criterion.

In your case, the criterion of interest is that the startup exceeds a valuation of $5$ billion, which is equal to $p = (0.01)(1 - 0.87) = 0.0013$.  The random number of such startups meeting this criterion out of a fixed sample of $n = 10$ startups is therefore a binomial random variable $X$ with parameters $n = 10$ and $p = 0.0013$, and the desired probability corresponds to calculating $\Pr[X \ge 2]$, which is precisely what you have described.

---

In general, it is useful to note that $X$ is an example of a *counting* variable.  This is in contrast to the random variable that models a random startup's valuation, which we might denote as $Y$.  We do not actually have complete access to the distribution that $Y$ follows:  we only have a table of probabilities, namely $$\Pr[Y \ge 1] = 0.01, \\
\Pr[1 \le Y \le 5 \mid Y \ge 1] = 0.87, \\
\Pr[5 < Y \le 10 \mid Y \ge 1] = 0.95, \\
\Pr[Y > 10 \mid Y \ge 1] = 1.$$
So if your criterion were different, say you wanted to know if a startup had a valuation exceeding $7$ billion, you would *not* be able to answer this question.  You could compute bounds on the probability, but there is insufficient information about $Y$ to characterize $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response.